# Facing problem during installing react project and setting up of Node Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to setup a ReactJS app on Windows using the following command in Git Bash:

`npx create-react-app my-app`

and the output is coming as :

`Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Dell\desktop\react-portfolio-website-1.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

Aborting installation.
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting react-portfolio-website-1/ from C:\Users\Dell\desktop
node:fs:1226
return handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
^

Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir '\?\C:\Users\Dell\desktop\react-portfolio-website-1'
at rmdirSync (node:fs:1226:10)
at _rmdirSync (node:internal/fs/rimraf:235:5)
at rimrafSync (node:internal/fs/rimraf:193:7)
at Object.rmSync (node:fs:1275:10)
at Object.removeSync (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\remove\index.js:15:28)
at C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:539:14
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
errno: -4082,
syscall: 'rmdir',
code: 'EBUSY',
path: '\\?\C:\Users\Dell\desktop\react-portfolio-website-1'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
`

I always face this problem, expected to get new react js project.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost same issue, I had to change my terminal for VSCode from Powershell to bash, then I ran these commands and it worked.

npm cache clean --force

npx create-react-app (project name)

Hope this should help you

Answer (score 0):

Are you on VPN or do you have any antivirus installed.  Try disabling it and then running npx create---